# Variable doesn't show up in R studio after using mutate function

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to create a new variable "season" from month variable by using the following script:

```
alldata_n %>%
mutate(
season = case_when(
  month %in% 10:12 ~ "Fall",
  month %in%  1:3  ~ "Winter",
  month %in%  4:6  ~ "Spring",
  month %in%  7:9  ~ "Summer" ))
```

This is working but when i use the function to see the variable, the "season" variable doesn't show up.

```
alldata$
```

I tried to save the data in csv format but even then the save data doesn't show any "season" variable. Where am i going wrong? Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you did not store the results of your code to an object.. try `newdata <- alldata_n %>% mutate( .... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues with this piece of code.

1. The variable `alldata_n` is mutated, but never stored.
2. Observe that the name `alldata` is not equal to `alldata_n`

So it should look like:

`alldata <- alldata_n %>%` 
`mutate(`
`season = case_when(` 
  `month %in% 10:12 ~ "Fall",` 
  `month %in%  1:3  ~ "Winter",` 
  `month %in%  4:6  ~ "Spring",` 
  `month %in%  7:9  ~ "Summer" ))`

Calling `alldata$season` now works.

Comment: thank you, it worked. The issue was i was not storing it to any other new data.